# need to convert the binary values to numbers

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed, solaris

I have a file with below data

```
cat test.txt
010001010000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

two fields in above line represents usage one digit starting from 16

I want the the o/p in such that if 01 then it should print the digit, else put , and check next field.

first two fields 01 means 16 is used so it should be printed in o/p file
2nd two field 00 mean 17 is not used, so it should not be printed in o/p file
ans so on.

Like wise there are 4000 fields, means 2000 digits starting from 16-2016

For above line , need output like

```
16,18,19,22,23,
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
cat counter_mfd.txt | cut -d\' -f2 | sed 's/.\{2\}/& /g' | awk -F, '{a[$2]=$1;} END{for(i in a)print i" "a[i];}'
```

awk: record `00 00 00 00 00 00 00...' too long

Comment: Cool - that gets my prize for the maddest data storage method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as **Perl** is pretty normal on Solaris:

```
perl -e '$s=16; foreach (<>=~m/.{2}/g){if($_=="01"){print "$s,"};$s++}' < test.txt
```

**Output**

```
16,18,19,22,23,
```

**Explanation**

`$s` is just the starting value.

`foreach (<>=~m/.{2}/g)` splits `stdin` into groups of two characters and then iterates over them setting `$_` to each one in turn.

The `if` checks if 2-digit string is `"01"` and prints `$s` if it is.

Then `$s` is incremented whether the value was printed or not.

Comment: Thanks .. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem I'm going to assume that the number of fields is an even number and that the data values are either `00` or `01`.  If these assumptions are correct, then you could do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub pairs_from_line {
    my $line = shift;
    my @elems = split(//, $line);

    my @data;
    while (@elems) {
        push @data, join('', splice(@elems, 0, 2));
    }

    return @data;
}

my $line = "0100010100000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
my @data = pairs_from_line($line);

my $conversion = 16;
map { print "$conversion," if ($_ == 1); $conversion++ } @data;
```

This code first converts the input data into a list of pairs (via the `pairs_from_line()` sub), from which we can convert the binary data into the output values you wish to have.  The function works as follows: it splits the input line into its individual elements ([`split(//, $line)`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)) and creates an array of pairs of these elements by taking two elements at a time ([`splice(@elems, 0, 2)`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)) and then joining them together via [`join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).  The array of pairs is then returned.

To create the output you want, it's just a matter of iterating over the array of pairs<sup>1</sup>, printing the value of the conversion factor if the pair evaluates to `1`<sup>2</sup>, and updating the conversion factor for each pair as the array of pairs is processed.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've chosen to use a [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) here, but one could equivalently use a [C-style `for`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) loop to achieve the same result.

<sup>2</sup> Which is what the string `"01"` will resolve to if it is compared in numeric context, e.g. via the `==` operator as used in this case; see the [Perl documentation about equality operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for more information about which operators to use in string or numeric context.